# Working two Array PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have two arrays: array1 [POP1, POP2, POP3 .... POP30] and array2 [61,61,62 ... 61]. I need to create a new object with value 62 and its POP.

In this example:

POP3 62.

I am simplifying the explanation because I've already been able to get the value from the database.

Can someone help me?

Code:

```
$target = @( )
$ini = 0 | foreach {
    $apiurl = "http://xxxxxxxxx:8080/fxxxxp/events_xxxx.xml"
    [xml]$ini = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).downloadstring($apiurl)

    $target = $ini.events.event.name
    $nodename = $target

    $target = $ini.events.event.statuscode
    $statuscode = $target
}

$column1 = @($nodename)
$column2 = @($statuscode)

$i = 0
($column1,$column2)[0] | foreach {
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        POP    = $Column1[$i]
        Status = $column2[$i++]
    } | ft -AutoSize
```

Comment: What is your question here? What doesn't work as expected?

Comment: I don't know how your code is working

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your intent is to create an array of custom objects constructed from the pairs of corresponding elements of 2 arrays of the same size:

A concise pipeline-based solution (PSv3+; a `for` / `foreach` solution would be faster):

```
$arr1 = 'one', 'two', 'three'
$arr2 = 1,     2,     3

0..$($arr1.Count-1) | % { [pscustomobject] @{ POP = $arr1[$_]; Status = $arr2[$_] } }
```

This yields:

```
POP   Status
---   ------
one        1
two        2
three      3
```

Answer (score 0):

I really couldn't figure out what you were trying to do, but you definitely over complicated it. Here is what I thought of your code:

```
# Here you have an empty array
$target = @( )

# Here you set call a Foreach, but you don't even need it
$ini = 0 | foreach {
    $apiurl = "http://xxxxxxxxx:8080/fxxxxp/events_xxxx.xml"
    [xml]$ini = (new-object System.Net.WebClient).downloadstring($apiurl)

    # You duplicated variables here. Just set $nodename = $ini.events.event.name
    $target = $ini.events.event.name
    $nodename = $target

    # You duplicate variables here. Just set $statuscode = $ini.events.event.name
    $target = $ini.events.event.statuscode
    $statuscode = $target
}

# You should already have arrays, so now you're making making more arrays duplicating variables again
$column1 = @($nodename)
$column2 = @($statuscode)

# counter, but you won't need it
$i = 0

# So here, youre making a new array again, but this contains two nested arrays. I don't get it. 
($column1,$column2)[0] | foreach {
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        POP    = $Column1[$i]
        Status = $column2[$i++]
    }  | ft -AutoSize
} # You were missing a closing bracket for your foreach loop
```

Here is a solution that should probable work for you:

```
# Download the file
$apiurl = "http://xxxxxxxxx:8080/fxxxxp/events_xxxx.xml"
[xml]$ini = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString($apiurl)
# Set arrays
$nodename = $ini.events.event.name
$statuscode = $ini.events.event.statuscode

# Create $TableValues by looping through one array
$TableValues = foreach ( $node in $nodename )
{
    [pscustomobject] @{
        # The current node
        POP = $node
        # use the array method IndexOf
        # This should return the position of the current node
        # Then use that index to get the matching value of $statuscode
        Status = $statuscode[$nodename.IndexOf($node)]
    }    
}

# Add a custom value
$TableValues += [pscustomobject] @{
    POP = 'POP100'
    Status = 100
}

$TableValues | Format-Table -AutoSize
```